# Google Analytics _ga cookie empty

Tags: cookies, google-analytics, analytics.js

I found out that **for some users of my website the _ga (client id) cookie is empty** while I really need it in my script for 100% of users.

I found this out by logging what's happening in my PHP script. This is strange to me, because for me the _ga cookie is always present, no matter which browser I use.

1) Why can the _ga cookie be empty?
2) Is there any way to force creating it? Or maybe there is another way to find out the client id of the user on the server-side?

Answer (score 0):

If javascript or cookies are disabled on client browser cookies always will be empty. You can implement additional logic on server to form an id from IP and/or User-Agent header of request if cookies are empty.